# Recursively parse all xml files and exclude folder

Tags: python, xml, lxml, elementtree

I am trying to parse all XML files in a given folder/subfolders and search and replace text inside that XML.  All while excluding the subfolder "Archive".  I am getting the error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'"  Not sure what I am missing, but my loop seems to die once it reaches the ElementTree to open and parse the XML.

```
for roots, dirs, files in os.walk("C:\test", topdown=True):
    if 'Archive' in dirs:
        dirs.remove('Archive')
    #dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if 'Archive' not in d]
    for f in files:
        if f.endswith('.xml'):
            try:
                with open(os.path.join(roots, f), 'r') as xml:
                  tree = ET.parse(xml)
                  root = tree.getroot()

                  for elem in root.getiterator():
                    try:
                      print (elem.text)
                      elem.text = elem.text.replace('_THUMBNAIL.jpg', '.mxd.jpg')

                    except ET.ParseError:
                        pass

                tree.write(xml, encoding='utf-8')
            except FileNotFoundError:
                pass
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that not all XML tags have a text. So you should use

```
if elem.text is not None :
    try:
        print (elem.text)
        elem.text = elem.text.replace('_THUMBNAIL.jpg', '.mxd.jpg')
```

Comment: hmm no dice.  It seems to skip everything with this.

Comment: Can you show a small part of your xml ? Seems strange.